# How to place random dots in string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have code

```
import random 
lst = ['.'] 
string = 'o3oyrwrj0jtirvwp5sh57oed67d5zy' 
print ''.join('%s%s' % (x, random.choice(lst) if random.random() > 0.5 else '') for x in string)
```

It generates string with random dots between symbols:

> o3.oy.r.wrj.0jt.i.rv.w.p5sh57.oe.d6.7.d.5z.y
>
> o3oyr.wr.j.0.j.ti.rvw.p5sh5.7o.e.d6.7.d5zy
>
> o.3o.y.rw.r.j.0.jt.i.r.v.wp.5sh.5.7.oe.d6.7.d5.zy

I need to generate string with number of dots from 1 to 10, and **except results**

dot at the end `'o.3.oyrwrj.0.jt.irv.wp.5.s.h57oe.d.67.d.5.zy.'`

dot in the begin  `'o.3.oyrwrj.0.jt.irv.wp.5.s.h57oe.d.67.d.5.zy'`

double+ dot  `'o..3.oyrwrj.0.jt.irv.wp.5.s.h57oe.d.67.d.5.zy'`

**I need only from 1 up to 10dots (not 10+)**

Comment: It doesn't really look like an exception-worthy issue? You just want to disregard those results?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: this code doesn't produce any results when I run it

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I get `o.3oy.r.wr.j0.jt.ir.v.w.p.5sh5.7o.ed6.7.d5zy.` once I put parentheses around `print()`

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at `for x in string`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede yeah, because this is a python 2.7 question and you're running in Python 3 without converting `print` into a function call. That's not the OP's fault...

Comment: I already have parentheses `print(''.join('%s%s' % (x, random.choice(lst) if random.random() > 0.5 else ('') for x in     string)))`

Comment: @rogan not saying OP is lying, but I would like to assist, just not sure why not running, I could peel apart the loop, just being lazy i guess

Comment: there shouldn't ever be a double dot with your syntax as it is, you always have x followed by either dot or nothing

Comment: @vash_the_stampede >>> import random 
>>> lst = ['.'] 
>>> string = 'o3oyrwrj0jtirvwp5sh57oed67d5zy' 
>>> print ''.join('%s%s' % (x, random.choice(lst) if random.random() > 0.5 else '') for x in string)
o3oy.rw.rj.0j.t.ir.vw.p5.sh.5.7.oed.67.d5z.y
>>>

Comment: @timgeb      I need only from 1 up to 10dots (not 10+)    For example: o3oy.rwrj0jtirvwp5sh57oed67d5zy,     o3oy.rwrj.0j.tirv.wp5.sh.57.o.ed67.d5.zy

Comment: @MarkAnt already working on it , just solving the doubles portion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `random.sample` to select a random set of indices at which you will insert a dot instead of drawing at each index.

Forming slices out of these indices and joining with `'.'.join` will prevent pairs of dots as well as heading and trailing dots if you exclude first and last indices.

```
from random import sample

def insert_dots(s, k):
    indices = sorted(sample(range(1, len(s) - 1), k))

    intervals = []

    for i, j in zip([0] + indices, indices + [len(s)]):
        intervals.append(s[i:j])

    return '.'.join(intervals)
```

### Example

```
s = 'foobar'

for _ in range(5):
    print (insert_dots(s, 3))
```

### Output

```
fo.o.ba.r
fo.ob.a.r
f.oob.a.r
fo.o.b.ar
fo.o.ba.r
```

If you need a random number of dots, you can then do this.

```
insert_dots(s, randint(1, 10))
```

Comment: OP is using Python 2.7.  I think unpacking within a list isn't going to fly. ;-)

Comment: @DSM oh right, you get so accustomed to those nice features

Comment: @Olivier Melançon I tried insert_dots('o3oyrwrj0jtirvwp5sh57oed67d5zy', 10)
and I see  pairs of dots
root@vid:~# python k.py
o3oyrwrj0jtirvwp5sh...oyrwrj0jtirvwp5.sh57oe.....jtirv.wp5sh57oed67d5zy
root@vid:~# python k.py
o3oyrwrj0.jtirvwp5sh57oed.67d5....3oyrwrj0jt.irvwp5sh57oed67...rwrj0jtirvwp5sh57oed67d5zy

Comment: @MarkAnt my bad, I forgot to sort the indices. See the updated answer.

Comment: @Olivier Melançon,  thanks a lot!! It's works as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if statement:

```
if string.startswith('.')
    # Raise dot at the beginning exception
elif string.endswith('.'):
    # Raise dot at the end exception
elif '..' in string:
    # Raise double dot exception
```